# Rails Active Storage direct uploads using default storage service instead of service defined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have specified in my model I would like a file to be stored using a non-default service (in this case just a different s3 bucket).

```
  has_one_attached :video, service: :s3videos
```

When I submit a standard form everything works.  But when I specify that I want direct upload I get a CORS error from my default service, not the one I want.  Here's my form field:

```
<%= f.file_field :video, direct_upload: true %>
```

Is it the case that direct uploads will always use the default storage - or can I specify the service I want somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue and there's a fix in the works!

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38957